# Complete Gibberish Error Message

Tags: cfml, lucee

I'm getting a really error message from Lucee:

```
‹Ä½írÛH’(úûöS`5'ÚîØ–D|zÚž (ÊR[”´$m¹gcc"!-à dyïØw¸¿nÄ9/·Or3I PdÖÌ9Û–å¬Bf}äweþðë¿œ^g¿ßŒ”e¼ò”›O'—CåàðøøVŸÎN•/ç³ñ¥¢u”Yhû‘»o{ÇÇ£«å`Çë_ŽŸŸŸžõ£ |8žMŽ¿â\...
```

The whole page is nothing but this gibberish.

I'm completely at a loss. Has anyone ran across something like this before?

Comment: Looks like it might be compiled code and considering it's CF then maybe it's java byte code?

Comment: How do you know it is an error message? Could be binary. Could be encoded. Could be encrypted. etc

Comment: I have no idea what it is what is causing it

Comment: Did anything change that made this begin happening? New hardware/software/network/upgrade/install/uninstall? If not then start with where you are seeing this. What page? Look at the code for that page. What is it doing? We can't really provide much help with the limited amount of information you have provided thus far. The question will likely be closed if you don't provide more info.

Comment: The file must have gotten corrupted somehow. I resaved it and it worked again.